# Flutter ElevatedButton onPressed functions Avoid using unnecessary statements

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Flutter stateful widget inside a [Stepper](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Stepper-class.html) widget, and it looks like this:
[image]

The first step of the stepper widget has another widget as its content, and that widget is a stateful widget as below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ConductorStart extends StatefulWidget {
  const ConductorStart({
    Key? key,
    required this.continued,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final VoidCallback continued;

  @override
  ConductorStartState createState() => ConductorStartState();
}

class ConductorStartState extends State<ConductorStart> {
  int _currentStep = 0;
  bool _pressedButton = false;

  void tapped() {
    setState(() => _pressedButton = true);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        if (!_pressedButton)
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              tapped;
              widget.continued;
            },
            child: const Text('Continue'),
          )
        else
          const SizedBox.shrink(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The `ElevatedButton` has two functions when called: `tapped`, and `widget.continued`. `tapped` should make the button disappear. and `widget.continued` is a function from the parent widget that is supposed to make the parent widget to continue to step 2 when clicked. Currently the two functions have a warning of `Avoid using unnecessary statements`, and they do not get executed properly. When I click the `continue` button. Nothing happens. What did I do wrong here?

Comment: perhaps enabling tracing might help?

Comment: Looking at your code - in Dart can you call a function without ()?  In your onPressed I would expect `tapped();` and `widget.continued();`  I've only seen function names without () when they're passed as an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll totally go with Pat9RB. Just posting it here as an answer for others to quickly find the relevant issue.

Adding just definitions helps for adding a callback parameter in the constructor.
For Eg.: `onPressed: myOnPressed;`
where, `onPressed` needs a `VoidCallback`, and `myOnPressed` is a `VoidCallback` argument.

But, you need to call the function in order to execute it from any other function body.
Either call using `.call()` method, like, `tapped!.call();` or append with callback syntax `()`, like, `tapped();`

Comment: adding `tapped(); widget.continued();` solved the problem!